# Loop through all possible RGB combinations

Tags: vb.net

What im trying to do, is change the `BackColor` of *form2* (on a click of a checkbox), to a smooth fade through all the possible colours, so from RGB: 0, 0, 0 all the way up to 255, 255, 255. Thank you.

This is what im doing:

```
Private Sub CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox2.CheckedChanged
    Dim lngR As Long
    Dim lngG As Long
    Dim lngB As Long

    For lngR = 0 To 255
        For lngG = 0 To 255
            For lngB = 0 To 255
                Me.BackColor = RGB(lngR, lngG, lngB)
                Sleep(30) 'change this value to change speed
            Next lngB
        Next lngG
    Next lngR
End Sub
```

And the error im getting is: `Value of Integer cannot be converted to Color.`

Comment: SO is not a place where you say "this is what I want to do, how do I do it". It's a place where you say "this is what I want to do, this is how I'm trying to do it and this is what happens when I try it, how do I fix it". If you haven't already done appropriate research and made an attempt then posting here is premature.

Comment: My mistake, sorry. Updated my post.

Comment: Your nested loops got to go.  Use a single loop and set each rgb component to the same value.

Comment: Second, rgb() produces an int value [you should really read the documentation].  You want Color.FromArgb().

Comment: @SamAxe : Setting each RGB component to the same value will cause it to fade from black to white only, not through all possible colours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the color change by adding Refresh() after changing the back color. This slows down the loop enough to see the color change but you are looping approximately 16.6 million times (very fast if you are not repainting all the time but very slow with the repaint) and will cause the user to fall asleep.

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        Dim intR As Int32
        Dim intG As Int32
        Dim intB As Int32
        'Alpha channel is implicitly opaque (255))
        Dim x As Integer = 0
        For intR = 0 To 254 Step 20
            For intG = 0 To 254 Step 20
                For intB = 0 To 254 Step 20
                    Threading.Thread.Sleep(10) 'change this value to change speed, 500 is 1/2 second
                    '16.6 million loops Wow - cut that down by using Step
                    Me.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(intR, intG, intB)
                    Refresh()
                    x += 1
                Next
            Next intG
        Next intR
        MessageBox.Show($"Red = {intR}, Green = {intG}, Blue = {intB}{vbCrLf}The value of x is {x}")
    End Sub
```